# Ignoring an entire stylesheet with @media

Tags: css, media-queries, rules

Alright so I'm attempting to build a responsive design, and one of the things that needs to be done is to ignore an entire style-sheet for an image slider (as the one I'm using has fixed dimensions when using a particular theme).

So, is there any way to just ignore every css rule that's in that particular file?

Comment: Can you just not include the file? That'd be one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be to not load the css on that page programmatically.

Otherwise you could specify the device or viewport width (whatever you use for sizing) to only load your stylesheet when the screen size matches.

Something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="alternate.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just display:none on the sliders container on each media query you dont want it featured?